# Which is the default value for "cancelable" for initialized event

Tags: javascript, dom

In the specs I read:

> The bubbles and cancelable attributes must return the values they were initialized to.

I cant find a paragraph pointing out the default behavior of an event.
Is it cancelable, is it not, is it undeterministic?

Comment: Which spec is that exactly?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-event-cancelable

Comment: So this about the DOM API, not really JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each case it can be initialized to different values. See quote from [Firing events](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#firing-events):

> Fire in the context of DOM is short for creating, initializing, and
>   [dispatching](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-dispatch) an [event](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event). [Fire an event](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-fire) makes that process
>   easier to write down. If the [event](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event) needs its `bubbles` or
>   `cancelable` attribute initialized, one could write "[fire an
>   event](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-event-fire) named `submit` with its `cancelable` attribute initialized
>   to true".

But it can also be initialized to false. An example from [HTML5 Scripting](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#execute-the-script-block):

> [Fire a simple event](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event) named `afterscriptexecute` that bubbles (but
>   is not cancelable) at the [`script`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) element.

When [firing a simple event](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event), the default is not cancelable:

> **Firing a simple event named `e`** means that a [trusted](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#concept-events-trusted) event with the name `e`, which does not bubble (except where otherwise
>   stated) and is not cancelable (except where otherwise stated), and
>   which uses the [Event](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#event) interface, must be created and
>   [dispatched](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#concept-event-dispatch) at the given target.